# Jmeter scripting when the number of requests sent are changing every time

Tags: jmeter

We have a web application based on Vaadin which I am trying to performance test. The application has reports. So whenever I open a report , internally it sends some Get and Post calls,some of these asynchronous calls. The problem is the number of the requests sent internally vary every time I open the report. For Example, first time 5 requests are sent/reveived, second time seven requests ,third time about 11 requests and next time again five requests etc., randomly. So when I recorded , say if it was five requests, during replay it fails. Is it possible to script around these issues?

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to test Vaadin web application performance with JMeter](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/articles/JMeterTesting.html) article:

> In Vaadin 7 there no more exists a `setDebugId()` method; instead there is `setId()` method. Unfortunately this method won’t set component ids used in the ajax-request. Therefore, by default, JMeter tests of a Vaadin 7 application are not stable to UI changes. To overcome this problem you can use our `JMeterServlet` (see the end of this article) instead of the default `VaadinServlet`. When using the `JMeterServlet` component ids are again used in the ajax requests. See example above for how to replace default VaadinServlet with JMeterServlet. For additional information, see the Vaadin ticket [#13396](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/4937).

Also replaying recorded AJAX requests is not the best idea because real browser executes AJAX requests in parallel while JMeter executes HTTP Request samplers sequentially which gives totally different network footprint so consider putting these HTTP Request samplers which mimic AJAX calls under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)